# javax.Servlet.ServletException:cannot find component with identifier ":form:display"

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

Hi i need to create a accordian panel with a datatable inside the tab1 but i am  geeting the following error:: javax.Servlet.ServletException:cannot find  component with  identifier ":form:display" ,can anyone plz help me out to resolve this error using primefaces.i need to work without using widgets.

**view.xhtml**

```
<h:form prependId="false" id="form">  

<p:dataTable id="dataTable" var="car" value="#{tableBean.getList()}"  
             paginator="true" rows="10"  selectionMode="single" selection="#{tableBean.selectedCar}" rowKey="#{car.model}" 
             paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport}  {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} {RowsPerPageDropdown}"  
             rowsPerPageTemplate="5,10,15">  
    <f:facet name="header">  
        Posted Jobs  
    </f:facet>  

    <p:column>  
        <f:facet name="header">  
            <h:outputText value="Model" />  
        </f:facet>  
        <h:outputText value="#{car.model}" />  
    </p:column>  

    <p:column>  
        <f:facet name="header">  
            <h:outputText value="Year" />  
        </f:facet>  
        <h:outputText value="#{car.year}" />  
    </p:column>  

    <p:column>  
        <f:facet name="header">  
            <h:outputText value="Manufacturer" />  
        </f:facet>  
        <h:outputText value="#{car.manufacturer}" />  
    </p:column>  

    <p:column>  
        <f:facet name="header">  
            <h:outputText value="Color" />  
        </f:facet>  
        <h:outputText value="#{car.color}" />  
    </p:column>  
      <f:facet name="footer">  
        <p:commandButton id="viewButton" value="View" icon="ui-icon-search"  
               update=":form:display" oncomplete="carDialog.show()"    actionListener="#{tableBean.add}"
                />  
    </f:facet>

</p:dataTable>  
 <p:dialog id="dialog" header="Car Detail" widgetVar="carDialog" resizable="false"  
          width="200" showEffect="clip" hideEffect="fold">  

    <h:panelGrid id="display" columns="2" cellpadding="4">  



        <h:outputText value="Model:" />  
        <h:outputText value="#{tableBean.selectedCar.model}" />  

        <h:outputText value="Year:" />  
        <h:outputText value="#{tableBean.selectedCar.year}" />  

        <h:outputText value="Manufacturer:" />  
        <h:outputText value="#{tableBean.selectedCar.manufacturer}" />  

        <h:outputText value="Color:" />  
        <h:outputText value="#{tableBean.selectedCar.color}" />  
    </h:panelGrid>  
</p:dialog>  

  </h:form>
```

**AccordionPanel.xhtml**

```
<h:head>
    <title>Accordion Panel</title>
</h:head>
<h:body>

    <h:form>
        <p:accordionPanel>
<p:tab id="DataTable1" title="DataTable 1">
<ui:include src="view.xhtml" />
  </p:tab>
  <p:tab id="DataTable2" title="DataTable2">
</p:tab>
</p:accordionPanel>
    </h:form>

</h:body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you move the `dialog` outside the form and try to use `update=:display`?

Comment: hi view.xhtml will be working fine but getting the error javax.faces.FacesException - Cannot find component with identifier ":display"  while running AccordionPanel

Answer (score 3):

You are getting this error because the update target of your commandButton can not be found using the specified component reference on the rendered html.

```
<p:commandButton id="viewButton" value="View" icon="ui-icon-search"
 update=":form:display" oncomplete="carDialog.show()" actionListener="#tableBean.add}"/>
```

Try removing the `update=":form:display"` so that your page can render, check the generated component id of the display panelGrid with Firebug and use that id in your update target.

Since primefaces version 3.1 component referencing is aligned with the JSF Spec. See this link for further information [UI Component findComponent()](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/UIComponent.html#findComponent%28java.lang.String%29)

Comment: if i removed  update=":form:display" it wont gives selected row contents in the dialog box,only header values will be displayed in the dialogbox

Comment: you are going to temporarily remove it to see what the component id of your panelgrid is (the one that you want to update), then replace :form:display with that.

Answer (score 1):

update your (update=":form:display") attribute on commandButton to this :

update=":form:dialog:display"

Comment: hi i tried that one also,if i do so it will give the following error : java.lang.IllegalArgumentException - Intermediate identifier dialog in search expression dialog:display identifies a UIComponent that is not a NamingContainer